# WCF client application hangs

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm a newbie to WCF technology. My current problem is that my windows forms app isn't getting a respond from wcf program. Here is the code for my windows forms app :

```
WCFService.PMSService obj = new WCFService.PMSService();      
string xx = obj.Test("Hello");
MessageBox.Show(xx);
```

My windows forms app hangs on this line -> string xx = obj.Test("Hello");

Here is the code for wcf my program :

### Interface/Declaration page

```
 // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPMSService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string DetermineGender(PersonalInfo pInfo);

        [OperationContract]
        string Test(string val);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public enum Gender
    {
        [EnumMember]
        Male,
        [EnumMember]
        Female,
        [EnumMember]
        None
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations
    [DataContract]
    public class PersonalInfo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string surname
        {
            get { return surname; }
            set { surname = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string idNo
        {
            get { return idNo; }
            set { idNo = value; }
        }
```

### Implementation page

```
 // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class PMSService : IPMSService
    {
        public string DetermineGender(PersonalInfo pInfo)
        {
            Gender Result = Gender.None;

            int idNo = Convert.ToInt32(pInfo.idNo.Substring(6, 4));

            if (idNo >= 5000)
                Result = Gender.Male;
            else
                Result = Gender.Female;

            return Result.ToString();
        }

        public string Test(string val)
        {
            return "U passed " + val;
        }
    }
```

Does anybody know the possible cause ?

Comment: How are you hosting the service? Are you using IIS or a console application, for example? Where is the binding and endpoint configuration of the service?

Comment: @Alberto IIS. Here are the config settings :

Comment: <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceTutorial.PMSServiceBehavior" name="WcfServiceTutorial.PMSService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceTutorial.IPMSService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

Comment: <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfServiceTutorial.PMSServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to the service or used Fiddler or something to verify you're actually hitting the service?

Comment: @chosenOneThabs WCFService.PMSService is your proxy? Does your IIS website has an authentication or you're just hosting only the *.svc file? If you're hosting the service using this last one, check the contract you're implementing in the SVC file. Check the server-side errors using Fiddler or something like that to see these errors.

Comment: Try turning on exceptions by setting the includeExceptionDetailsInFaults to true in your config above. Just make sure you turn it off again before you go to production.

Comment: @Mark let me try fiddler. I try to enable includeExceptionDetailsInFaults as well.

Comment: @Alberto im using .svc page.My IIS is on my local machine.

Comment: I got it right. The problem was that I didn't add the web service reference properly. I've added the reference under Advanced page("Add Service Reference-> Advanced -> Add Web Reference") instead of "Add Service Reference" page. Advance page works fine with ASMX web services. Now I'm initializing my web service object this way :

WCFService.PMSServiceClient obj = new WCFService.PMSServiceClient();

Answer (score 1):

The best suggestion (and perhaps so obvious that many overlook) for someone new to WCF is to become familiar with WCF Tracing and Message Logging.  The WCF tracing functionality provides a relatively simple, built-in method to monitor communication to/from WCF services.  For test and debugging environments, configure informational or verbose activity tracing and enable message logging.  The combination of activity tracing and message logging should prove beneficial when initially deploying and testing new services or adding new operations and/or communication bindings to existing services.

The following links provide a good overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx

Comment: i will try your suggestion as well. I will keep you posted.